# Is it possible to bypass/ignore an argument in a custom function

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, arguments

**Just for clarification,** not intended to reopen, as I will start a follow-up question:

- This not a question about using an `ifelse` in `dplyr`.
- This is a question about passing by an argument in a custom **function**. This is important for certain (not mentioned) reasons!

**Original question**:

I have this example with the `mtcars` dataset:

- Where basically the dataframe is filtered and then plotted.
- I wonder if it is possible to make the plot of the unfiltered data by this function ignoring the filtering variable `z`:

```
# create a custom function
my_function <- function(df, x, y, z) {
  df %>% 
    filter(am == z) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = {{x}}, y={{y}}))+
    geom_col()
}
```

**apply function with filter am==0** <- WORKS

```
my_function(mtcars, cyl, mpg, 0)
```

**apply function with filter am==1** <- WORKS

```
my_function(mtcars, cyl, mpg, 1)
```

**would like to ignore the filter argument to get plot of all data** <- WORKS NOT

```
my_function(mtcars, cyl, mpg)

Error in `filter()`:
  ! Problem while computing `..1 = am == z`.
Caused by error:
  ! argument "z" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: You could check if the argument was supplied and conditinally perform the filter: `my_function <- function(df, x, y, z) {hasz <- !missing(z); df %>% {if (hasz) filter(., am==z) else .} %>% ggplot(aes(x = {{x}}, y={{y}})) +geom_col()}`

Comment: @MrFlick. It seems that you are quite experienced here. This question is closed. But I don't understand why. This not a question about using an ifelse in dplyr. This is a question about passing by an argument in a custom function. As you can see that I have already a little experience and I am following a certain quest. In this case my ultimate goal is to solve  the last line of my function: `anim_save(paste0("images/survival_", z, ".gif"))`. And if z = NULL it starts to save all other ever filtered images. But the first was to understand how to bypass an argument. Could you clarify. Many thnx

Comment: You framed the question as you were interesting in conditionally filtering data only under certain circumstances.  I was unable to guess what your true intention was. But there are plenty of existing questions about testing if a parameter has passed. I can add a duplicate for that if you like as well.

Comment: @MrFlick. Now after going through all again. I think you are right. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is about working with the default.

I'd suggest having a default z = NULL,
then your function would look like this.\

```r
# create a custom function
my_function <- function(df, x, y, z = NULL) {
  
  if (!is.null(z)) {
   df <-  df %>% 
      filter(am == z)
  }
  
df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = {{ x }}, y = {{ y }})) +
    geom_col()
}

my_function(mtcars, cyl, mpg, 0)

my_function(mtcars, cyl, mpg, 1) 
my_function(mtcars, cyl, mpg)
```

Comment: You can also use `if (missing(z))` (and don't need  a default setting), but I prefer your solution.

Comment: Yes, it looks more obvious that `z` is different variable type than x and y.

Comment: @olivroy. Thanks this solved also my main issue, i.e how to save without the filter argument!

Comment: @olivroy, also easier if the function is being called indirectly (it's easy to force a parameter to be `NULL`, very hard to force it to be "missing")